# Fitting data in form $f = f_0 + c A^x$

Tags: functions, fitting, data

The `Fit[]` function in Mathematica can fit data in form of $f = f_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+...$ ($f_0$ and $c_i$ are unknown constants), is there a function can fit date in form of $f = f_0 + cx^a$, where $a$ may be not an interger?

Comment: Yes, `FindFit`, `NonlinearModelFit` can all handle this; `Fit`, `LinearModelFit` will also work if `a` is known constant and not a parameter to be fitted.  If `a` is not an integer, it will help if all `x > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

or `NonlinearModelFit[]`. With this function you can also extract the errors and other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try `FindFit[]`. This function can fit a data set to arbitrary functions.